# When I Am Trying To Insert Data in Hive I have get ParseException

Tags: sql, hive

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student(
    > Student_Name STRING,
    > Student_Rollno INT,
    > Student_Marks FLOAT)
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    > FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
OK
Time taken: 0.667 seconds
```

```
hive> INSERT INTO TABLE student VALUES ('Dikshant',1,'95'),('Akshat', 2 , '96'),                               ('Dhruv',3,'90');
NoViableAltException(26@[])

FAILED: ParseException line 1:26 cannot recognize input near 'VALUES' '(' ''Diks                               hant'' in select clause
```

Comment: 95 and 96 in quotes are not float types, but you appear to have another syntax issue, such as not ending the line on a semicolon